# NSArray of NSDictionaries as a query parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession, nsurlrequest

I need to send an NSArray of NSDictionaries as a query parameter in a GET request for NSURLRequest. An example of what I would like to send is this:

```
[{"name":"John","age":20},{"name":"Bob","age":25}]
```

I was sending this via AFNetworking with the following:

```
- (NSString *)makeJSONString {
    NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (RDPerson *person in [self.people allValues]) {
    NSDictionary *currentPerson = @{@"name" : person.name, @"age" : person.age};
    [mutableArray addObject:currentPerson];
    }
    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:mutableArray options:0 error:&error];
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return jsonString;
}
```

Now that I have moved my code to NSURLSession, this is not working, so what is the proper way to put this object into a query parameter?

The part that isn't working is

```
[self.urlSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
```

This completion handler is returning null for the data and response

SOLUTION:
SO it turns out before you commit this to the URL you have to do this for your url:

```
[mutableString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

then set this to the URL with URLWithString

Comment: Whats not working about it? Please add some more details.

Comment: Please post the code that is not working so that we can see what may be the matter.  Also, in general, you will not want to convert the JSON to a string, but leave it as ```NSData```.

Comment: A proper way is to use an entity ("body") at your requests, a large json is hardly a parameter. If you want minimal changes, check your full URLs to be valid and complete, might have to encode and decode some parameters with such approach.\

Comment: And continuing with A-Live's observation, to put the JSON in the body of the request, the request should be a `POST` request, not a `GET` request. `GET` requests have no body, whereas `POST` requests do. And if you want to be a good net citizen, you should set the `Content-Type` HTTP header to be `application/json` when you prepare this `POST` request.

Comment: ya these are the parameters I'm putting after the base URL

Answer (score 1):

**WARNING:** Your proposed solution is **not** correct and can potentially cause a security hole, not to mention that it may fail randomly in unpredictable ways, for two reasons:

1. The `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` is almost invariably the wrong method to call.  It is deprecated because it does not work correctly.

   If you need to support any version of iOS prior to iOS 9, use `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`.
2. You should **not** be encoding an entire URL at once.  You should always encode **only** the actual blob of arbitrary data that you are adding to the URL, e.g.

   ```
   NSString *JSONBlob = ...
   NSString *encodedJSONBlob = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)
       CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
           kCFAllocatorDefault,
           (__bridge NSString *)JSONBlob,
           NULL,
           CFSTR(":/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;="),
           kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

   NSString *URL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/.../foo.cgi?myparam=%@&foo=bar", encodedJSONBlob];
   ```

   Otherwise, the encoding method may double-encode parts of the URL that have already been encoded.

For details, see: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/WorkingwithURLEncoding/WorkingwithURLEncoding.html

And as others have mentioned, if your JSON data is large, you should be sending it in a POST body instead.